# Record not working (permission checked)

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I've been struggling to get recording working with nginx-rtmp module. The folder for the recording has broad permissions (777), I tried both manual via control endpoint or automatic recording. Nothing seems to work.

```
application stream {
            live on;

            record all;
            record_suffix .flv;
            record_path /tmp/recordings;
            record_unique on;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 750k -f flv -g 30 -r 30 -s 640x360 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_360p878kbs;
        }
```

RTMP streaming is working, I also have HLS working fine, but nothing gets written to the `/tmp/recordings` folder.

Nothing on the error logs.

The source can be found here: https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/docker-nginx-rtmp-1

Configuration:

- Nginx 1.12.0 (compiled from source )
- nginx-rtmp-module 1.1.11 (compiled from source)
- ffmpeg 3.3.2 (compiled from source)

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you're basically using an upstream docker, except for removal of some transcoding options from `ffmpeg`?  Perhaps the lack of those options is what's causing the issue?!

Comment: No it's not that, I've removed the extra encodings because I did not needed more than one quality of video.

Comment: How to test this from a Mac?

Comment: @ViniciusCarvalho, of course, but I think it's a mistake to just assume that your own changes, how little and inconsequential they may seem, have no effect on the outcome